# How can I spy on a function exported from a module in Jasmine 2?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine2.0

Source Code

```
  import lookupFooFunction from '../../utils/sampleJSFile';
    function a() {
      const a = 'bla';
      const b = 'zoo';
      lookupFooFunction(a,b) 
      //more stuff
    }
```

Test Code

```
spyOn(window, 'lookupFooFunction');
expect(viewInstance.caFormView.lookupStarRewardsPhone).toHaveBeenCalledWith('bla','zoo');
```

I want to be able to spy on my call to lookupFooFunction and use toHaveBeenCalledWith, but since lookupFooFunction is not an object I can't figure out how to do so.

When I do the above I get the error message Error:  : lookupFooFunction() method does not exist.

Googled things more and found that the window object shouldn't work because I'm having the same problem as this person here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jasmine-js/a3gNCMMd3UM However, I haven't been able to get things to work with jasmine.createSpy and I'm not clear if that approach could work.

Comment: I ended up modifying my code to export an object with my function as a property.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
spyOn(window, 'lookupFooFunction');
```

isn't working,  you can use

```
lookupFooFunction = jasmine.createSpy();
```

as alternate Jasmine syntax to create a spy.  [Here's a CodePen](https://codepen.io/joewilson0/pen/mxWmoL) to play around with it if the StackOverflow code runner isn't working.

```js
// This will be imported, but is stubbed here
function lookupFooFunction(a, b) {
  return 123;
}

function a() {
  const a = 'bla';
  const b = 'zoo';
  lookupFooFunction(a, b);
}

it('test', () => {
  // Arrange - spy with jasmine.createSpy() or spyOn(window, 'lookupFooFunction')
  lookupFooFunction = jasmine.createSpy();
  //spyOn(window, 'lookupFooFunction');
  
  // Act
  a();
  
  // Assert
  expect(window.lookupFooFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('bla', 'zoo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.99.2/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.99.2/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.99.2/boot.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.99.2/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Hmm. That's not working for me either. I'm also getting an error when I run your code snippet. Also, I'm using Jasmine 2.99.

Comment: When I use jasmine.createSpy I get the error Uncaught Error: <toHaveBeenCalledWith> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on that it's not running on Stack Overflow. I changed the framework to 2.99.2 and it still runs for me in Chrome (latest). I added a CodePen so you can play around with it more easily. I also added a pretend `lookupFooFunction` to simulate the one you are importing.